# getUserMedia stopped working on Safari 10, no support

Tags: javascript, safari, camera, webcam, getusermedia

Since the release of **Safari 10** the method **getUserMedia()** has stopped working in order to access the video camera from the browser. I haven't found any alternative apart from Flash, but also Flash is deactivated by default in Safari 10 which makes it a bad solution.
Have you found a fix for this issue?
You can try the standard html getUserMedia from the demos section of this website and test how in Safari stops working https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Thanks.

Comment: Has there ever been support for Safari at all ? According to [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream), it does not look like it. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It was supposed to not work, but before Safari 10 if you opened the examples on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ they worked. And I had a project working on Safari. Now it's not working anymore :-S